# In a Wagtail multisite installation is there a way to link an article to additional sites in the UI?

Tags: wagtail

When you create an article in a Wagtail multisite installation is there an option in the UI to set the additional sites  where you want the article to show?

I have looked in the UI but can't find any such settings.

What I do now is to copy it to the other sites, and make it alias, but that isn't what the docs seem to suggest.

Is the alias method I'm using the right way, or am I missing something?